# How to configure dependent dropdown in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

| A header | Another header |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| salary | husband salary | wife salary |  |  |  |  |
| bonus | husband bonus | wife bonus |  |  |  |  |
| allowance | husband allowance | wife allowance |  |  |  |  |
| Other | Husband's Additional Income | Wife's Additional Income | Husband's Investment Income | Wife's Investment Income | Husband's Other Income | Wife's Other Income |

I have data like above.

In this case, *salary*, *bonus*, *allowance*, and *other* refer to major categories.

If I select *salary* as a dropdown in cell A2, I want the sub-items of *salary*, which are *husband salary* and *wife salary*, to be displayed as dropdowns in B2.

What I've currently done is to only allow major category items to be selected through dropdowns.

But I don't know how to load that sub-item.

I don't want to manually specify the range in Data > Data Confirmation as a major category may get renamed or items may be later added and/or deleted.

Comment: You need a extra helper sheet for data structure. Then you can use formula and dropdown from ranges in main sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would go about it.  I made another sheet which I named "Dropdowns".

In A2 of this sheet, I set up a `Data Validation - Dropdown (from a range)` which selects your main categories (A2:A from the original sheet, in the case of this sample, "Sheet1").

[image: Screen1]

Then in B8 of the original sheet, I use a formula that refers back to Dropdowns!A2.

Here is the formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Dropdowns!A2=A2,B2:2,IF(Dropdowns!A2=A3,B3:3,IF(Dropdowns!A2=A4,B4:4,IF(Dropdowns!A2=A5,B5:5,)))))

This is saying if the value in Dropdowns!A2 is equal to A2 on this sheet (which in this case, is *salary*), then populate this cell with the values associated with this sheet's A2 value, otherwise, if Dropdowns!A2 is equal to A3 on this sheet (which in this case, is *bonus*), then populate this cell with the values associated with this sheet's A3 value...and so on.

Since it is an `arrayformula`, B8:B will be populated with the values associated with each major category.

In the screenshot below, since *salary* is selected in Dropdowns!A2, the associated values are in B8:8.

[image: Screen2]

Then in Dropdowns!B2 set up a `Data Validation - Dropdown (from a range)` that is populated from B8:8 on the original sheet.

[image: Screen3]

Everything should now be configured properly.

**Alternative solution per comment:**

In the event that new categories will be added or there is a lot of data, consider using this formula:

> =FILTER(B2:5,A2:A5=Dropdowns!A2)

(Change the B2:5 to cover whole range of sub-categories as necessary.)

I would not put this in B8, however, since you may need to add more data that extends into that range.  One idea is to drop the headers down one row on original sheet ("Sheet1" in my sample) and put this formula in A1.  Then your `Data Validation - Dropdown (from a range)` in Dropdowns!B2 should be populated by data in A1:1.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation (A2:A from the original sheet). What does it mean to be an original sheet?

Comment: The original sheet is the sheet you already have on your spreadsheet.  In the case of the sample I made, "Sheet1".  I then added another sheet for the dropdowns.  I called this sheet "Dropdowns".

Comment: I understand. However, Dropdowns!A2=A2, Dropdowns!A2=A3, Dropdowns!A2=A4.. These conditions may become too many..

in a slightly simpler way

If there is a value (ex. income) that I am looking for in a specific area, can't I get row information based on that value?

For example, when the value I am trying to find is allowance, and the area is the entire area, I want to get only the values to the right (husband allowance, wift allowance) based on the allowance.

Comment: Added alternative solution to the answer.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work for you?